# Tkinter text insert: " 'Nonetype' object has no attribute 'insert'

Tags: python, user-interface, insert, tkinter, nonetype

Relatively new to coding in general, and have been trying to create a simple chat client for Python. Trying to work the GUI, and have encountered the problem shown below.

I have a functioning GUI and use the "example.get()" function to retrieve the string text from an entry box. The program then prints the text to the command prompt (Just to prove it's been retrieved) and then should place it in a text box, however it gives me a "Nonetype" error. Code is below. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Thanks

```
from tkinter import *

#Create GUI
root=Tk()
root.title("Chat test")
root.geometry("450x450+300+300")

#Declare variables
msg=StringVar()

#Get and post text to chat log
def postaction():
    msg1=msg.get()
    print(msg1)
    chatlog.insert(INSERT,msg1+'\n')
    root.mainloop()

#Build GUI components
chatlog=Text(root, height=10, state=DISABLED).pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
entry=Entry(root, textvariable=msg).pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
button=Button(root, command=postaction, text="Button").pack()
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `.pack` method of a widget always returns `None`.  So, you need to place the calls to `.pack` on their own line:

```
chatlog=Text(root, height=10, state=DISABLED)
chatlog.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
entry=Entry(root, textvariable=msg)
entry.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
button=Button(root, command=postaction, text="Button")
button.pack()
```

Comment: This fixed the Nonetype error, however it still doesn't post to the chatlog. Any ideas?

Comment: @QuarterGeekster - Oh, sorry.  I didn't see that.  You can fix that problem by simply removing the `state=DISABLED` part of the line where you make the textbox.  Having it makes the textbox unusable.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I can finally move on to other things!